# Digitized polygon not lining up with others of same coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, digitizing

To start: I created a new polygon shapefile to represent an old site boundary. I set the spatial reference at the time the shapefile was created. I then started an editing session and digitized a polygon from a JPG image (I set the spatial reference for this image too).

I need to overlay the old site boundary (the polygon I just created) on top of an updated site boundary polygon (already existed). My problem is that when I add the polygon I just created to the map, it doesn't show up with everything else. It has the same coordinate system and everything as the rest of the map.

Any suggestions? I'm sure it's an easy answer but I've tried everything I can think of at the moment.

EDIT:
Software: ArcMap 10.7.1

Spatial reference of digitized polygon:

```
Projected Coordinate System:    NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_12N
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting:  500000.00000000
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian:   -111.00000000
Scale_Factor:   0.99960000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0.00000000
Linear Unit:    Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

Spatial reference of preexisting polygon/map canvas:

```
Projected Coordinate System:    NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_12N
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting:  500000.00000000
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian:   -111.00000000
Scale_Factor:   0.99960000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0.00000000
Linear Unit:    Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify what GIS software you are using (with the exact version), the coordinate reference of your map canvas, the coordinate reference of the image, and coordinate reference of the shapefile.

Comment: @Vince I added them above. Thanks!

Comment: Do the extents of both feature classes have similar values or vastly different ranges?

Comment: You said you set the crs of the image, but is your JPG image actually georeferenced? Is there a jgw file along with the image? If you only set a crs without georeferencing the image, then I guess that is why the coordinates don't match up, because ArcMap will show the image near 0,0 if there is no georeference information with it.

Comment: @PolyGeo You're right, the extent for the digitized feature class is off. How do I fix that?

Comment: @FSimardGIS I think you're right! I totally spaced on having to georeference the image. I'll do that now. Thank you!!